# Tweet text vanishes when adding mention or hashtag

Tags: ios, twitter, ios9, uiactivityviewcontroller

In my App, I'm using UIActivityViewController to have users share urls via Twitter. This worked great prior to iOS9. Ever since the update to iOS9, this feature shows a strange effect when adding mentions or hashtags to the tweet. Scenario like this:

- A user decides to share a url. User taps a button that opens an ActionSheet with all sharing options like SMS, WhatsApp, Email and Twitter.
- User chooses Twitter, tweet editor opens filled with the url. Everything good so far. 
  [image]
- User wants to add a mention or hashtag. User starts typing and selects an entry from the list of suggestions. 
  [image]
- **This results in the disappearance of the whole text from the tweet editor view**. The app doesn't crash, just the text vanishes. 
  [image]
- When adding a mention or hashtag just by typing @example_name or #examplehashtag rather than picking from the list, it works all fine.

I can observe the same behaviour on my iPhone 5S with soundcloud app, v3.14.0.

I'm sure others must have the same problem after updating to iOS9. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on an iPhone 6 running iOS 9.1.  It sounds like an Apple SDK bug though.  I'd create a small project where you can reproduce the error and submit it: https://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply. I saw this strange behaviour on other apps too. But than again, on many others it still works well. I also have no idea how I could troubleshoot this myself. I'll therefore try it with a bug report at apple.